# Java JSP exception Report

Tags: java, jsp, exception, servlets, report

I'm having a hard time with this code, every time  I test and run it, I always get the same error but cant seem to fix it. The error I'm getting is, can anyone help? Its the last thing I need to get done to get this project working!

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

```
exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    Servlets.addFunds.processRequest(addFunds.java:43)
    Servlets.addFunds.doPost(addFunds.java:95)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.
```

/*
     * To change this template, choose Tools > Templates
      and open the template in the editor.
     */

```
    package Servlets;

    import beans.UserBean;
    import eventaccess.DatabaseConnector;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    /**
     *
     * @author sberry3
     */
    @WebServlet(name = "addFunds", urlPatterns = {"/addFunds"})
    public class addFunds extends HttpServlet {

        /**
         * Processes requests for both HTTP
         * <code>GET</code> and
         * <code>POST</code> methods.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
                String url = null;

            double addFunds = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("addFunds"));
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            UserBean userSession = (UserBean) session.getAttribute("userSession");
            double balance = userSession.getBalance();
            balance = balance + addFunds;
            userSession.setBalance(balance);
            session.setAttribute("userSession", userSession);

            DatabaseConnector db = new DatabaseConnector();
            String queryString = "UPDATE USERS SET balance=" + balance + " WHERE userID=" + userSession.getUserID();

            try {
                db.createConnection();
                db.pstmt = db.conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                db.pstmt.execute();
                db.closeConnection();

                url = "/store.jsp";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response.setHeader("dbError", "Coudn't connect to database");
            }

            request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);   

        }

        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
        /**
         * Handles the HTTP
         * <code>GET</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        /**
         * Handles the HTTP
         * <code>POST</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        /**
         * Returns a short description of the servlet.
         *
         * @return a String containing servlet description
         */
        @Override
        public String getServletInfo() {
            return "Short description";
        }// </editor-fold>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what line it is where your `NullPointerException` is happening.

Some possibilities:

Missing request parameters. For example, if you requested the page without including the `addFunds` parameter, you get a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
double addFunds = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("addFunds"));
```

Missing session attribute:

What does the line

```
UserBean userSession = (UserBean) session.getAttribute("userSession");
```

return? Is `userSession` null? If so then later on:

```
userSession.setBalance(balance);
```

would cause a `NullPointerException`. I thinks that's the most likely problem. Do you something like

```
session.setAttribute("userSession", new UserSession());
```

anywhere?

Comment: Nope, still cant seem to get it working. I'll keep at it, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

On your first request to this jsp

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

will create a new session since there isn't an existing one. So

```
UserBean userSession = (UserBean) session.getAttribute("userSession");
```

will set `userSession` to `null`, since no Attribute `userSession` has been created up to this point.